# Optimize parts extraction

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica

I have this specific function to extract parts of a list in the form: `Give[list, elem]` returns the part of *list* that corresponds to the position of *elem* in a global `$Reference` variable (if defined). I use this function heavily throughout my code, so I decided to optimize it. This is where I managed to get so far, but frankly, I have no idea how to advance.

```
ClearAll[Give, $Reference, set];

Give::noref = "No, non-list or empty $Reference was defined to refer to by Give.";
Give::noelem = "Element (or some of the elements in) `1` is is not part of the reference set `2`.";
Give::nodepth = "Give cannot return all the elements corresponding to `1` as the list only has depth `2`.";

give[list_, elem_List, ref_] := Flatten[Pick[list, ref, #] & /@ elem, 1];
give[list_, elem_, ref_] := First@Pick[list, ref, elem];

Options[Give] = {Reference :> $Reference}; (* RuleDelayed is necessary, for it is possible that $Reference changes between two subsequent Give calls, and without delaying its assignment, ref would use previous value of $Reference instead of actual one. *)
Give[list_List, elem___, opts___?OptionQ] := Module[{ref, pos},
   ref = Reference /. {opts} /. Options@Give;
   Which[
      Or[ref === {}, Head@ref =!= List], Message[Give::noref]; {},
      Complement[Union@Flatten@{elem}, ref] =!= {}, Message[Give::noelem, elem, ref]; {},
      Length@{elem} > Depth@list - 1, Message[Give::nodepth, {elem}, Depth@list]; {},
      True, Fold[give[#1, #2, ref] &, list, {elem}]
]];



In[106]:= $Reference = {"A", "B", "C"};
set = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

Give[set, "B"](* return specified row *)
Out[108]= {4, 5, 6}

In[109]:= Give[set, "B", "A"] (* return entry at specified row & column *)
Out[109]= 4

In[110]:= Give[set, {"B", "A"}] (* return multiple rows *)
Out[110]= {{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

I've decided to drop distinct signature function calls, as the list version might call the non-list version, which means that error handling has to be done multiple times (for each element in the list). Sadly, the error handling cannot be discarded. If the improved version is more robust (can e.g. handle more dimensions), that's not a problem, however the examples above will suffice.

```
In[139]:= First@Timing[Give[set, RandomChoice[$Reference, 10000]]] (* 1D test *)

Out[139]= 0.031

In[138]:= First@Timing[Table[Give[set, Sequence @@ RandomChoice[$Reference, 2]], {10000}]] (* 2d test *)

Out[138]= 0.499
```

I'm sure this is not efficient code, so feel free to improve it. Any help is appreciated, even if it trims off only a few nanoseconds.

Comment: István, what did you think of our answers?

Comment: Forgive me, I did not forget to evaluate your solutions, but at the moment I'm busy writing my thesis. Early results indicated that neither of the solutions could yield considerable time-gain due to the specific calls in my code, so I've immediately abondoned this route to make my simulations faster. Until I have more time to delve into it again, I won't conclude on the matter. Please be patient.

Comment: I understand.  I hope that your thesis goes well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main efficiency problem for large lists seems to come from mapping `Pick`. This can be avoided if you replace the corresponding definition for `give` with this one:

```
give[list_, elem_List, ref_] := 
    list[[elem /. Dispatch[Thread[ref -> Range[Length[ref]]]]]];
```

Here is my test code:

```
In[114]:= 
  Block[{$Reference = Range[100000],set = Range[100000]^2,rnd,ftiming,stiming},
      rnd = RandomSample[$Reference,10000];
      ftiming = First@Timing[res1 = Give[set,rnd]];
      Block[{give},
        give[list_,elem_List,ref_]:=list[[elem/.Dispatch[Thread[ref->Range[Length[ref]]]]]];
        give[list_,elem_,ref_]:=First@Pick[list,ref,elem];
        stiming = First@Timing[res2 = Give[set,rnd]];];
   {ftiming,stiming,res1===res2}
]

Out[114]= {1.703,0.188,True}
```

You get 10 - fold speed increase here, for this use case. I did not test the 2D one, but would guess it should help there too.

**EDIT**

You could further improve performance by caching the dispatched table for `$Reference` (`Dispatch[Thread[ref->Range[Length[$Reference]]]`) once at the start in the body of `Give`, and then pass it to `give` (either explicitly or by making `give` an inner function  - through `Module` variables - which would refer to it), so that you don't have to recompute it in case when you call `give` several times through `Fold`. You can also do that conditionally, say of you have large lists of elements in `elem`, to justify the time needed to create the dispatch table.

Comment: I did not realize at first, that you are using the same small values for `$Reference` and `set` for your power tests. My solution will not help much when the lists are very small. In the 2D case, you surely have a large function call overhead. If you must produce results one by one, I don't see a way to avoid that. If you often need to produce multiple results at once (like in your test with `Table` for 2D), you might be able to optimize your function further. So, my question is - is your second test artificial (`Table` there just to do a benchmark), or do you often have cases like this?

Comment: Well, finally I got to the point to evaluate this thread. To answer your question: yes, the second benchmark was quite realistic: I had to use the very same `$Reference` and `set`. I also should tell you, that in the last 2 years I have abondoned, rewritten, forgot, buried and rewritten again this code. At the end I used memoization to save the dispatch table. I guess my coding improved **a lot** in these two years as I don't seek solutions with such an unnecessary (though verbose) overhead anymore...

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution for this problem based on a problem I had for indexing real numbers. It uses lazy evaluation to display an error message if needed (a trick I learned on this site! Thanks to all for your dedication, it's always a pleasure to learn new stuff here!)

```
ListToIndexFunction[list_List,precision_:0.00001]:=
   Module[{numbersToIndexFunction},

      numbersToIndexFunction::indexNotFound="Index of `1` not found.";

      MapThread[(numbersToIndexFunction[#1]=#2)&,{Round[list,precision],Range[Length@list]}];
      numbersToIndexFunction[x_]/;(Message[numbersToIndexFunction::indexNotFound,x];False):=Null;

      numbersToIndexFunction[Round[#,precision]]&
   ];

Test: 
f=ListToIndexFunction[{1.23,2.45666666666,3}]
f[2.456666]
f[2.456665]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Leonid's answer, but in my own style.

I use the same `Dispatch` table, and I recommend making this as external as possible.  To this end, I suggest a new symbol `$Rules` that is updated whenever `$Reference` is changed.  For example:

```
$Reference = RandomSample["A"~CharacterRange~"Z"];

$Rules = Dispatch@Thread[$Reference -> Range@Length@$Reference];
```

This can be made automatic for convenience, if it is done frequently (ask).

Aside from this, my complete code:

```
ClearAll[Give, $Reference, Reference, $Rules];

Give::noref = "No, non-list or empty $Reference was defined to refer to by Give.";
Give::noelem = "Element (or some of the elements in) `1` is is not part of the reference set `2`.";
Give::nodepth = "Give cannot return all the elements corresponding to `1` as the list only has depth `2`.";

Options[Give] = {Reference :> $Reference};

Give[list_List, elem___, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{ref, pos, rls},
   ref = OptionValue[Reference];
   rls = If[{opts} == {}, $Rules, Dispatch@Thread[ref -> Range@Length@ref]];
   Which[
    ref === {} || Head@ref =!= List,
        Message[Give::noref]; {},
    Complement[Union@Flatten@{elem}, ref] =!= {},
        Message[Give::noelem, elem, ref]; {},
    Length@{elem} > Depth@list - 1, 
        Message[Give::nodepth, {elem}, Depth@list]; {},
    True,
        list[[##]] & @@ ({elem} /. rls)
   ]
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! As I mentioned it to Leonid under his answer, I simplified this problem in the last 2 years, so got rid of all the messages and - following your approach - made the syntax entirely relying on `Part`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I got after letting this piece of code rest for 2 years. It memoizes the dispatch table for the given reference set, and uses the `Part`-type syntax. I got rid of all the error messages and also dropped the global `$Reference` symbol. Very un-*Mathematica*-like and I never liked it.

```
dispatch[ref_] := dispatch@ref = (Dispatch@Thread[ref -> Range@Length@ref]);
give[list_, elem__, ref_] := list[[Sequence @@ ({elem} /. dispatch@ref)]];
```

Memoization ensures that the dispatch table for a given `ref` is only calculated once. Maintaining multiple dispatch tables in memory is not a problem as these are usually small.

```
ref = Reference = {"A", "B", "C"};
set = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

give[set, "B", ref]          (* ==> {4, 5, 6}              *)
give[set, "B", "A", ref]     (* ==> 4                      *)
give[set, {"B", "A"}, ref]   (* ==> {{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Timing:

```
n = 20000;
{
First@Timing[give[set, #, ref] & /@ RandomChoice[ref, n]],
First@Timing[give[set, RandomChoice[ref, n], ref]],
First@Timing[Table[give[set, Sequence @@ RandomChoice[ref, 2], ref], {n}]]
}
```

> ```
> {0.140401, 0., 0.202801}
> ```

Compare this to the timings of the original function:

```
{
First@Timing[Give[set, #] & /@ RandomChoice[ref, n]],
First@Timing[Give[set, RandomChoice[ref, n]]],
First@Timing[Table[Give[set, Sequence @@ RandomChoice[ref, 2]], {n}]]
}
```

> ```
> {0.780005, 0.015600, 1.029607}
> ```

Comment: I like this. (+1) I also think I might have written something similar if the question had been asked now, two years later, though I would have tried to keep your error messages.  Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: By the way, you might consider using the memoization syntax I proposed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121